# How to resolve "Error in PGOcc(occ.formula = ~Vegetation + Distance_National_Park + Distance_Shore + : c++ error: dpotrf A.alpha failed"?

Tags: r, species

I have been trying to using the spOccupancy R package for occupancy modelling to map an endangered species range. My data is formatted as follows:

> ```
> List of 4
>  $ y       :'data.frame': 93 obs. of  3 variables:
>   ..$ X1: int [1:93] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>   ..$ X2: int [1:93] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>   ..$ X3: int [1:93] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
>  $ occ.covs:'data.frame': 93 obs. of  8 variables:
>   ..$ Vegetation            : num [1:93] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
>   ..$ Distance_National_Park: num [1:93] 65090 60283 64489 66261 66209 ...
>   ..$ Distance_Shore        : num [1:93] 217.9 174.5 141.3 66.7 170 ...
>   ..$ Distance_Village      : num [1:93] 1473 224 430 316 447 ...
>   ..$ Distance_Cages        : num [1:93] 28405 23286 27355 29386 29294 ...
>   ..$ Cages_Present_Binary  : int [1:93] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
>   ..$ Water_Depth           : num [1:93] -103 -18.7 -27.7 -33.9 -33.9 ...
>   ..$ Fishing_Intensity     : num [1:93] 0.0771 0.5926 0.5323 0.4951 0.4951 ...
>  $ det.covs:List of 5
>   ..$ Start_Time : num [1:93, 1:3] 930 990 600 645 711 933 534 862 900 330 ...
>   .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
>   .. .. ..$ : NULL
>   .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "X1" "X2" "X3"
>   ..$ Duration   : num [1:93, 1:3] 12 22 5 7 5 27 18 47 9 122 ...
>   .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
>   .. .. ..$ : NULL
>   .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "X1" "X2" "X3"
>   ..$ Day        : num [1:93, 1:3] 97 97 98 98 98 102 103 103 108 124 ...
>   .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
>   .. .. ..$ : NULL
>   .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "X1" "X2" "X3"
>   ..$ Survey_Team: num [1:93, 1:3] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>   .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
>   .. .. ..$ : NULL
>   .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "X1" "X2" "X3"
>   ..$ Length     : num [1:93, 1:3] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7530 ...
>   .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
>   .. .. ..$ : NULL
>   .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "X1" "X2" "X3"
>  $ coords  : num [1:93, 1:2] -69.3 -69.3 -69.3 -69.3 -69.3 ...
>   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
>   .. ..$ : NULL
>   .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "X" "Y"
> ```

I ran the following code:

```
Grebe2022_Occ_Formula <- ~Vegetation + Distance_National_Park + Distance_Shore +
  Distance_Village + Distance_Cages + Cages_Present_Binary + Water_Depth

Grebe2022_Det_Formula <- ~ Start_Time + Duration + Day + Survey_Team + Length

PGOcc(occ.formulaGrebe2022_Occ_Formula, det.formula = Grebe2022_Det_Formula, 
    data = Grebe2022, n.samples = 5000, n.burn = 3000, n.thin = 2, 
  n.chains = 3)
```

And got the following error message:

```
Error in PGOcc(occ.formula = ~Vegetation + Distance_National_Park + Distance_Shore +  : 
  c++ error: dpotrf A.alpha failed
```

I have tried to ask for help in StackOverflow, but was told that there must be more to the error message. I can assure any readers that this is the entire error message. I am not sure what it means, let alone how to solve it.

Comment: Is there a typo where you call the model `PGOcc(occ.formulaGrebe2022_Occ_Formula` - it looks wrong. Its not the cause of the problem you are having but seeing typos in questions makes us think you're not giving us a reproducible example. Further to that, although we've got a summary of your data we can't easily build a data set to test with. Can you either supply us with the data (via a file sharing site) or construct a sample data set in code with dummy values that shows the same error? Have you tried simplifying your formula in case its a problem with a single column?

Comment: I have corrected that typo, and I get the same error. I have simplified it to be one covariate for occurences and one for detection, and get the same error, which makes me think that it is an issue with how the dataset is formatted,  but I am not sure. I can put the data as dput(head(data, f)) if that is sufficient?